# Vancouver to Auckland options with non-alliance flights on long haul routes?

Tags: air-travel

What routes exist from Vancouver to New Zealand if I'd like every leg longer than three hours be on a low cost / non-alliance flight? (These airlines typically have much more affordable premium economy or business class tickets.) One example is Westjet to Honolulu and then Jetstar to Sydney or Melbourne -- this is what I did in 2015.

Note this is near impossible to search with automated tools: the airlines in question might not be in Matrix, the flights in question might only be on certain days and so the connection might be >24hrs and so on.

Comment: Perhaps one could start from https://www.aucklandairport.co.nz/flights/airlines-contacts. A very quick glance indicates Jetstar/Virgin as options. Honolulu seems like the must-pass connection mid route given the aircraft limitations of most low cost airlines. Seasonal offers may also vary. There are many flights to Hawaii in winter from low cost/charter/vacation airlines, but not that many in summer: unfortunately for you, Auckland and Vancouver's seasons are reversed.

Comment: That's actually another reason for the impossibility of automated search: the long haul flight could be to Sydney, Melbourne, Fiji... And yes, it's very likely Honolulu needs to be involved.

Comment: Air Tahiti Nui is non-alliance but still pricey. Fiji Air may be a good compromise if you want to avoid HNL.